# How do I launch vuze?

Tags: launcher

I am new to Ubuntu. I went to the software center in Ubuntu 12.04 and installed Vuze. But I cannot find a way to run the program.  I installed VLC and K3b and there is an icon for them on the left side of the screen.  They work fine, but I can not figure  out how to run Vuze.  Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried opening the Dash (The top button on the launcher on the left side of the screen) and typing Vuze

Comment: That worked great! Thank you so much.  I have a lot to learn.  Jeanne

Comment: @Jeanne If that worked, could you hit the tick icon to the left of the answer below, to mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 3):

If Vuze has been successfully installed it's icon should have been added to the launcher automatically. It is possible that you might have added a number of new programs which has resulted in there not being enough space on the launcher to show them all at the same time. If you place your mouse at the bottom of the launcher then it will scroll down to show you more icons.

If for some reason the icon hasn't automatically been added to the launcher try using the dash (it is the top button on the launcher:

[image]

press the button and type **Vuze** and you should see the application there to click on.